# How to create struct with variable name

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I would like to create a struct that is named after a dynamic variable.
Something like:

```
for t = 1:2

    for b = 1:70
        Father.t.b.A = A;
        Father.t.b.C = C;
    end
end
```

and when looking at `Father` there is `Father.1.1.A`, `Father.1.2.A`, ... , `Father.2.70.C`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Variable names, including structure field names, [cannot start with a number](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html). Use an array of structures: `Father(t, b).A = A`;

Comment: You should definitely do as @excaza has shown rather than the answer below as it is much cleaner and easier to read and understand.

Comment: @Suever is right, it's not a good practice to use my answer, I just wanted to show you the syntax.

Comment: @Rotem it is good practice to use dynamic field names, it's just not at all applicable to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB allows for arrays of structures that can be indexed similarly to its other arrays:

```
for t = 1:2
    for b = 1:70
        Father(t, b).A = A;
        Father(t, b).C = C;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample to create the `struct` (like excaza mentioned, field names starting with a number are not allowed):

```
A = 1;
C = 3;

for b = 1:7
    Father.(['b', num2str(b)]) = struct('A', A, 'C', C);
end
```

Now:

`Father.b1.A` equals 1
`Father.b5.C` equals 3